# Joomla 4 Upgrade issue with custom component

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-component

I have a custom component that I've inherited. I've upgraded the site to Joomla 4 with no problems but when going to the frontend, am getting an error:

```
Fatal error: Class CloudCardModelCard contains 1 abstract method
and must therefore be declared abstract or
implement the remaining methods
(Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ItemModelInterface::getItem) in
public_html/components/com_cloudcard/models/card.php on line 3
```

The file referenced above is as follows:

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class CloudCardModelCard extends JModelItem {

}
```

Any ideas what I can do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The ItemModel class (JModelItem) that you are extending with your class CloudCardModelCard is defined as abstract in Joomla 4.

```
abstract class ItemModel extends BaseDatabaseModel implements ItemModelInterface
```

However your CloudCardModelCard class is not defined as abstract

```
class CloudCardModelCard extends JModelItem
```

Therefore the message is saying you need to change your class statement to

```
abstract class CloudCardModelCard extends JModelItem
```

or you need to put all the methods found in ItemModel into your own class, which isn't that big an issue as there is only method to copy

```
protected function getStoreId($id = '')
{
    // Compile the store id.
    return md5($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. Your model needs to implement `getItem()` method required by the `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ItemModelInterface` interface. This method is meant to be used for retrieving a single content item as an object. If your model already has a similar method named differently (e.g. `getCard()`), you can proxy `getItem()` to this method:

```
public function getItem($pk = null)
{
    return $this->getCard($pk);
}
```

If your model does not have/need such functionality, consider extending a less specific model such as `Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel`.